# Cohesive forces in solid solutions

Tags: bond, ionic-compounds, solid-state-chemistry

I have searched through printed books and the Internet, but I cannot find a definitive answer on an issue that fascinates me: what forces keep the various compounds belonging to a solid solution together?

If I correctly understand, a rock is a solid solution, and I know that the atoms of a single mineral species are bound by its particular covalent and ionic bonds, but what keeps different minerals together in a rock? Do they mix by sharing "neighbouring" cations and anions? I am not sure whether intermolecular forces such as Van der Waals forces are present, but I would definitely expect stronger forces in a solid solution or between the minerals of a rock.

Comment: Pure compounds and solutions are held together by the same types of forces.

Comment: No need to thank it's very general answer, you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_solution for some details, and generally rocks aren't solid solutions.

Comment: @Mithoron Nevertheless, I suspect that the forces keeping rocks together are the same that keep solid solutions together: am I wrong? Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you were on right path - for example common [feldspars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldspar) are [solid solutions](http://%20en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_solution) and they are mixed because they share cations, while they easily substitute one another, otherwise they exsolve - become separate phases. Also you're right that [van der Waals forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) aren't important here as they are ionic compounds.